torch.nn.MultiheadAttention with need_weights=False still returns a tuple of length two, is it expected
For an object of nn.MultiheadAttention class when I use the forward method with need_weights=False, it still returns a tuple of length two. Is it expected? I was expecting it to only return the attn_output.
See the toy example below:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# Create an instance of MultiheadAttention
embed_dim = 64
num_heads = 8
multihead_attn = nn.MultiheadAttention(embed_dim, num_heads)

query = torch.randn(10, 5, embed_dim)  # (seq_len, batch_size, embed_dim)
key = torch.randn(10, 5, embed_dim)
value = torch.randn(10, 5, embed_dim)

# Call the forward method
output = multihead_attn(query, key, value, need_weights=False)
len(output)

# I should do
attn_output = output[0]


You will notice the second returned element is in fact None when need_weights=False.
